# How to fix discrepancy in transaction nonce after Hedera Testnet reset?

Tags: json-rpc, hedera-hashgraph

Prior to the Testnet reset, the transaction nonce on an EVM account was being picked up correctly.

However, after the Testnet reset, there is a discrepancy:

- `eth_getTransactionCount(address, 'latest')` returns a low number (`0` before sending my first transaction after the reset)
- `eth_getTransactionCount(address, 'pending')` returns a high number (`140` in my case, which probably was the nonce prior to the reset)

(Using a DApp, connected through Metamask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metamask caches the transaction nonce for accounts.

Therefore after the reset, you need to clear its cache. To do so:

Metamask --> Settings --> Clear activity tab data

[image]

After this, your nonce should reset to `0`, and the `eth_getTransactionCount` discrepancy should stop happening.